# Why the sorting of custom product options does not work when you move the mouse?

Tags: magento2, product, javascript, custom-options

[image]

I can't put the item elsewhere. It always stays in its place.
There are no errors in the browser console.

As I understand the logic of moving an object is in the file: `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/dynamic-rows/dnd.js`

Debugged and saw that the expression on line 284:  `rec[0] === this.draggableElement.originRow[0] ? 'none' : position` , always returns true => 'none'

But I don't understand what's wrong.

Magento 2.4.5-p2